# upload a file in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Hi I want to upload a file using cake php, i got the file and i am using 
  move_uploaded_file() to move to a specific location but it is not moving my simple logic is
  shown below

```
if (move_uploaded_file($this->data['Add']['upload']['tmp_name'], APP . 'views' . DS . 

    'static' . DS.'uploads'.DS.'Rajaram'.DS )) {
                LogUtil::$logger->debug('KMP File upload Url : 
    '.var_export($this->data, true));
            }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why `APP . 'views'`? This should not contain uploaded data. Use `APP . 'files'` or `APP . 'webroot'`.

Answer (score 1):

File uploading is something CakePHP doesn’t do out of the box, which is one of the only thing that annoys me about the framework.

I tackled this by adding file handling to a model using callback methods. I upload the actual file with `beforeSave()`, and delete the file from the file system with `beforeDelete()`. A sample model looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

class Image extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Image';

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $fieldName = 'filename';
        $field = $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName];
        if (!is_array($field)) {
            $this->validationErrors[$fieldName][] = 'No file detected';
            return false;
        }
        switch ($field['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $newFilename = time() . '.jpg';
                $uploadDir = WWW_ROOT . 'files/';
                $source = $field['tmp_name'];
                $destination = $uploadDir . $newFilename;
                if (move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)) {
                    $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName] = $newFilename;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    $this->validationErrors[$fieldName][] = 'No file detected';
                    return false;
                }
            break;
            default:
                $this->validationErrors[$fieldName][] = 'No file detected';
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
        $image = $this->findById($this->id);
        $file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $image['Image']['filename']);
        return $file->delete();
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn’t a perfect implementation, so feel free to take from it, learn from it, adapt it.

This was written off-the-cuff for a project recently where there’s only one model that has images attached, but on a larger project I’d more than likely wrap it up into a nice model behavior.

Comment: In my opinion, they should make it a model behavior. It would strike the right balance of flexibility without being constraining.

Comment: Yeah, that was my recommendation. The above is just something I used in a project where I needed to quickly add upload functionality to a model.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can use the afterSave callback method to handle your file upload:-

```
public function afterSave($created) {

    if (isset($_FILES['data']['name'][$this->alias]['filename'])) {

        $filename = $_FILES['data']['name'][$this->alias]['filename'];

        $fileInfo = pathinfo($filename);
        $fileExt  = isset($fileInfo['extension']) ? $fileInfo['extension'] : '';
        $filename = $fileInfo['filename'];

        $newFilename = "$filename.$fileExt";

        $dir = WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'uploads';

        $target = $dir . DS . $newFilename;

        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

    }

}
```

You can use $newFilename to change the filename to something appropriate if need be (I tend to check if a file with the same name already exists and rename the new one to avoid overwriting it.